# Binding checkbox to Datatable with YES/NO values

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, checkbox

I have checkboxes that needs to be bound to a DataTable. Problem is that checkboxes store "YES" and "NO" values in Oracle DB fields, NOT Boolean. How can I bind to those values ?

This doesn't work:

```
ChkInUse.DataBindings.Add("Checked", dtb, "IN_USE")
```

I get error: "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean".

EDIT (My full code):

```
    Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * from MyTable WHERE ID=" & Form1.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString

    Dim dtb As New DataTable()

   Using con As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection("Data Source=MyDB;User Id=Lucky;Password=MyPassword;")

        Try

            con.Open()

            Using dad As New OracleDataAdapter(SQL, con)
                dad.Fill(dtb)
            End Using

     ChkInUse.DataBindings.Add("Checked", dtb, "IN_USE")
```

Comment: Think you might need to create your check box class. Couple of things out there. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9ec1709f-4e06-4a77-8812-379d0d34a82c/checkbox-databinding-and-yn-values?forum=winformsdatacontrols

Comment: Thanks, but how to write Checkbox class, I have never done that ?...Sorry, I'm VB.NET beginner...And this is for C# If not mistaken.

Comment: in your SQL select, you can create a bool version: `"SELECT ... (IN_USE = 'YES') AS bInUse  FROM..."`  You would have to set/toggle the real column in the checkchanged event though.  What is `dtb`?

Comment: dtb is my Datatable.

Comment: see my edtied question, I posted full code now. Everything else - Comboboxes, Textboxes, DateTimePicker works like this, just checkboxes not.

Comment: When more than one person responds to a Q, you need to use `@` + `username` as in @LuckyLuke82 to reply to a specific person.  *You* get pinged for all posts because it is your question.  Since you only have one row at most in the query, just map the value manually.

Comment: @Plutonix, ok thanks for info. What did you mean by " map the value manually" ?

Comment: Yes, thinking about it, I would go with Plutonix suggestion. Just loop round each row in the data table and update the column to 1/0 depending if it's Yes/No then it should bind using the code you already have correctly. :)

Something like this

For each row As DataRow in dad.Rows
 If row("IN_USE") = "Yes" Then
  row("IN_USE") = "1"
 Else
  row("IN_USE") = "0"
 End If
Next

Comment: @RyanThomas, Ok, i'll try.

Comment: based on that SQL there can only ever be one row at most, so no loop is needed

Comment: @RyanThomas, I tried, code has error, or I don't use It properly. Tried with "dad" and "dtb" inside & outside of "Using", but "dad" and "dtb" gets error.

Comment: Sorry it should be dtb.Rows in the loop. What is the error?

Comment: @Plutonix, I'm sorry but I still don't have a clue where sohuld I do that - In SQL Query ?

Comment: I posted the answer 10 mins ago.  Refresh your page

Comment: @RyanThomas, I get same error as before: "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean".

Comment: Okay. instead of using 1 and 0 use "True" and "False" - that's how I got I've got it to work on my solution :)

Comment: @RyanThomas, jesus allmigthy, It works now !!! THANKS A LOT MAN !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are just loading one row, I would just set and fetch it manually:

```vb
dad.Fill(dtb)
' set the check
chkInUse.Checked = (dtb.Rows(0).Field(Of String)("IN_USE") = "YES")
```

`(dtb.Rows(0).Field(Of String)("IN_USE") = "YES")` is an expression resulting in a Boolean which is then used to set the `CheckState`.

Then in the check changed event:

```vb
' early exit if there is no datatable yet or no rows
If dtb Is Nothing OrElse dtb.Rows.Count < 1 Then Return
dtb.Rows(0)("INUSE") = If(chkInUse.Checked, "YES", "NO")
```

This does the reverse: sets the table text to "YES"|"NO" depending on the checked state.

The table would have to have *form level scope* (that is not clear in the question) and you will need to check if the table is valid and if there are any rows at all in the table (shown).

---

If you were dealing with multiple rows in the table and perhaps displaying it in a `DataGridView`, you could do something very similar in the `CellFormatting` and `CellParsing` events to translate back and forth from `YES` to True/Checked.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer:

```
Dim IN_USE_Bind = New Binding("Checked", dtb, "IN_USE", True)
'Transform coming from dtb to ChkInUse
AddHandler IN_USE_Bind.Format, Sub(o, c) c.Value = (c.Value = "YES") 'Don t care about NO
'Transform coming from ChkInUse to dtb
AddHandler IN_USE_Bind.Parse, Sub(o, c) c.Value = If(c.Value, "YES", "NO")
'ChkInUse.DataBindings.Clear()
ChkInUse.DataBindings.Add(IN_USE_Bind)
```